# div height 100% on mobile landscape mode?

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, css

i got a problem with a spritely-div which is cut in half when scrolled in landscape mode on mobile devices (maintains same height as initial screenheight). and i just cant get it fixed. ;-(

this is my URL:
http://skypirat.es/comingsoon/
and i am talking about the panning clouds.

if you turning your mobile into landscape mode and scroll down you´re getting this result:
http://hitclick.de/images/screen-skypirates.jpg
see the clouds cut in half?

any idea how i can give them height:100% so they are shown uncut - just like in portrait mode?

OR EVEN BETTER: make this div fixed? so that the clouds just stay where they are - only panning to the left (its fine, that one could only see the upper part of them) and only the text is scrolling?

i´ve been playing around with 'position', 'background-attachment', 'height:100vh', 'max-height: inherit' etc. but couldn´t solve this tricky problem. ;-(

thanks and greetings,
michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.stage` class (the class for the clouds) currently has `position: absolute`. Change that to `position: fixed`.

```
.stage {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but nope @dwreck08. tried this before. doesn´t change a thing (cache cleared, reloaded). ;-( EDIT: you can check this here http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http://www.skypirat.es/comingsoon/ (second demo)

Comment: That second demo you provided still has `position: absolute` for `.stage`. That has to be `position: fixed;`. Also note, I'm not talking about `background-attachement: fixed`. It has to be `position: fixed`

Comment: no @dwreck08, you must have had an old version (cache?). just have a look at the original website: it definitely has `position:fixed`!`.stage {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}`

and this is NEITHER overwritten in the index.html NOR the jquery.spritely.js file. so the same problem as originally mentioned still occurs. ;-( any other ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I just checked Chrome, Safari and Firefox with both of your provided links. Every browser has `.stage { position: absolute;}`

Comment: *aarghhh*  you are more than right @dwreck08 and i have to apologize a thousand times! i edited the WRONG .css file. i am very sorry, doesnt really get any more stupid than this! ;-)  of course your advice helped a lot.  clouds are now fixed and everythig looks perfectly fine!    thanks again!